# Express and npm install failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am getting errors trying to reinstall npm and express and cannot figure out how to resolve it.[image: npm]

[image: express]

I've tried:

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
npm install -g npm
```

and:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Comment: not sure about osx, but you should not be needing to use `sudo` for installling express. Try install node with https://github.com/creationix/nvm